# SIGSEGV error on saving many things at once to MySql with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Using sequelize when I'm doing more than 500 saves at once(400 is okay) I'm getting SIGSEGV error.
The error says:

> fish: “node app.js” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Some info:
I'm using sequelize, sequelize-connect and mysql modules.
Database is mysql.
User is default - root.
Kernel is Linux 4.4.19-1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in node. I had version 6.5.0, and when I switched to 4.5.0 everything is working.